# How to store data securely on iOS when background mode access is required?

Tags: ios, security, encryption, keychain, data-protection

I'm working on mobile application for iOS which has to store data securely and be able to download data from Bluetooth device in background mode.

I would like to know what would be the best approach to encrypt that data? I was thinking about using Data Protection and adding a proper file attribute to force encryption or doing it more manually by storing password hash in Keychain and encrypting file using AES with derived key based on that hash.

However, I'm a little bit worried about Keychain access flags, in my case I would have to use [kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecattraccessibleafterfirstunlock). Could anyone explain what does it mean exactly?

To sum up my concerns:

1. Is it possible to provide a good security in background mode?
2. What's the best approach?
3. kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock - does it mean that my data is not safe when user unlocks device after restart?
4. What if user doesn't have a passcode? Is data safe or not?

Thank you in advance for any help with this topic.

Comment: You should be able to use [`NSFileProtectionCompleteUnlessOpen`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfileprotectioncompleteunlessopen) Then you don't need to worry about the keychain

Comment: @Paulw11 unfortunately it doesn't solve problem completely, because application may be terminated (therefore file will be closed), but iOS is able to start the application from background when Bluetooth device becomes available. So in this case my file will be inaccessible. Also still the question remains - how security changes when using different attributes? Is the change visible only from application perspective or does it expose a file for attacks?

Comment: You would need to open and write to a new file and then merge those files when the app is in the foreground

Comment: Alternatively, `NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication`, may be sufficient for your needs; particularly with the new USB protections in iOS 12.

Comment: I was also thinking about merging files, but I'm not sure if this is the best available approach. However, combined with NSFileProtectionCompleteUnlessOpen seems to be reasonable. But I wonder if this is really necessary, is NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication not safe, if so what's the purpose of this attribute?

Comment: CompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication means that the files are decrypted after the first time the user enters their passcode after power on. You need to determine if this is a risk to you or not; iOS 12 improves USB security so it is harder for someone to attach a computer and download the decrypted files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I managed to do some more research and decided to share my conclusions based on Apple's document [iOS Security for iOS 11](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf).

All below is based on knowledge coming from the document and my personal interpretation. Therefore before applying this to your solution, please read the document carefully.

---

### Files are always encrypted on flash memory (local storage)

First of all, as I understand reading the document, files on local storage are never decrypted (even without any additional protection set).

> If a file isn’t assigned a Data Protection class, it is still
>   stored in encrypted form (as is all data on an iOS device).

However, enabling Data Protection we get one more level of protection which generates an encryption key for a protected file. But still no matter which protection class we pick, the file will remain encrypted all the time on local storage.

### How it works that we get decrypted data within the application?

> Every iOS device has a dedicated AES-256 crypto engine built into the
>   DMA path between the flash storage and main system memory, making
>   file encryption highly efficient.
>
> When a file is opened, its metadata is decrypted with the file system
>   key, revealing the wrapped per-file key and a notation on which class
>   protects it. The per-file (or per-extent) key is unwrapped with the class
>   key, then supplied to the hardware AES engine, which decrypts the file
>   as it is read from flash memory. All wrapped file key handling occurs
>   in the Secure Enclave; the file key is never directly exposed to the
>   application processor.

Therefore, all decryption happens 'on the fly' and files are still protected on flash memory.

[image]

### NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication

I'm not going to go into details for each protection class, however I would like to clarify this one. As I mentioned above, files are protected all the time, so what happens if we use class NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication? The answer is here:

> This class behaves in the same way as Complete Protection, except that the decrypted class key isn’t removed from memory when the device is locked.

Only our application can access the file, but the job is done here by Crypto Engine which has access to our *File Key* in memory, even if the device is locked and decrypts data from flash memory to system memory.

[image]

### Hardware security

It's worth to mention that hardware is also protected and even if you move flash storage to another device, it won't be possible to get its data.

> The UID allows data to be cryptographically tied to a particular device.
>   For example, the key hierarchy protecting the file system includes the
>   UID, so if the memory chips are physically moved from one device to
>   another, the files are inaccessible. The UID isn’t related to any other
>   identifier on the device.

### Jailbreak concerns

Is data still secure after Jailbreak?

Fortunately Data Protection mechanism uses passcode to decrypt data, therefore data will remain encrypted even after Jailbreaking your device unless a hacker cracks your passcode.

### Background mode

For applications which use background mode **NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication** should be enough. Apple mentiones that in section related with KeyChain access (which is quite similar):

> Apps that utilize background refresh services can use
>   kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock for Keychain items that need to
>   be accessed during background updates.